# Прерывание цикла/функции C++

Tags: c++, циклы, arduino

Нужно прервать выполнение цикла или функции в момент отпускание кнопки, именно остановить чтоб он прервался в нужном месте и не выполнялся до конца. К примеру кнопка нажата и цикл выполняется на примерно 30% и кнопка отпускается, и чтоб цикл прервался и не выполнялся до конца.

```
#include "DigiMouse.h";
boolean right_mouse_position;
int button_pinright = 1;
void setup() {
pinMode(button_pinright,INPUT);
pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
DigiMouse.begin();
}

void loop() {
right_mouse_position = digitalRead(button_pinright);
while(right_mouse_position == 1){
DigiMouse.setButtons(0);
DigiMouse.delay(1);
DigiMouse.setButtons(1<<0);
DigiMouse.delay(1);
//MoveR -4 8
DigiMouse.moveX(-4);
DigiMouse.moveY(8);
DigiMouse.delay(24);
//MoveR -4 7
DigiMouse.moveX(-4);
DigiMouse.moveY(7);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -4 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-4);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -3 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-4);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -3 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-3);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -2 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-2);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -1 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-1);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 0 5
DigiMouse.moveX(0);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 0 4
DigiMouse.moveX(0);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 0 4
DigiMouse.moveX(0);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -2 4
DigiMouse.moveX(-2);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -4 4
DigiMouse.moveX(-4);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -6 4
DigiMouse.moveX(-6);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -6 4
DigiMouse.moveX(-6);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -6 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-6);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -5 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-5);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -5 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-5);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -4 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-4);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -4 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-4);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -4 5
DigiMouse.moveX(-4);
DigiMouse.moveY(5);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -3 4
DigiMouse.moveX(-3);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -1 4
DigiMouse.moveX(-1);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR -1 4
DigiMouse.moveX(-1);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 0 4
DigiMouse.moveX(0);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 0 4
DigiMouse.moveX(0);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 1 4
DigiMouse.moveX(1);
DigiMouse.moveY(4);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 1 3
DigiMouse.moveX(1);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 2 3
DigiMouse.moveX(2);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 2 3
DigiMouse.moveX(2);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 2 3
DigiMouse.moveX(2);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 2 3
DigiMouse.moveX(2);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 2 3
DigiMouse.moveX(2);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 3 3
DigiMouse.moveX(3);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 3 3
DigiMouse.moveX(3);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 3 3
DigiMouse.moveX(3);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 3 3
DigiMouse.moveX(3);
DigiMouse.moveY(3);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 4 2
DigiMouse.moveX(4);
DigiMouse.moveY(2);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 5 2
DigiMouse.moveX(5);
DigiMouse.moveY(2);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 5 2
DigiMouse.moveX(5);
DigiMouse.moveY(2);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 5 2
DigiMouse.moveX(5);
DigiMouse.moveY(2);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 5 1
DigiMouse.moveX(5);
DigiMouse.moveY(1);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
//MoveR 4 2
DigiMouse.moveX(4);
DigiMouse.moveY(2);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
DigiMouse.setButtons(0);
DigiMouse.delay(100);
break;
}
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде много раз повторяется данное выражение

```
DigiMouse.moveX(...);
DigiMouse.moveY(...);
DigiMouse.delay(25);
```

при этом изменяются только данные. Можно все данные поместить  в 3(хотя т.к. задержка всегда одна и та же, то 2) массива или один 2-х мерный массив и с помошью цикла for пройтись по всем значениям. При этом в цикл можно вставить обработку нажатия кнопки

```
void loop() {
    right_mouse_position = digitalRead(button_pinright);
    while(right_mouse_position == 1){
        DigiMouse.setButtons(0);
        DigiMouse.delay(1);
        DigiMouse.setButtons(1<<0);
        DigiMouse.delay(1);
        for(int i=0; i<sizeof(ArrayX)/sizeof(int);i++){
             if(тут поставить проверку кнопки)break;
             DigiMouse.moveX(ArrayX[i]);
             DigiMouse.moveY(ArrayY[i]);
             DigiMouse.delay(25);
        }
       DigiMouse.setButtons(0);
       DigiMouse.delay(100);    
   }
```

вот примерный код, начале только нужно определить массивы ArrayX и ArrayY (туда просто поместить значения, которые ты передавал функциям DigiMouse.moveX() и DigiMouse.moveY(3)).

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы прервать выполнение цикла и выйти из него, используется оператор `break`; чтобы прервать и вернуться к его началу - оператор `continue`.

Вас это интересовало?

Comment: Да, но как это сделать если не известно когда нужно закончить. Нужно остановить цикл когда отпустится конопка. И в это момент цикл может выполнится только на 30%.

Comment: @Noname7258 проверяйте периодически состояние кнопки в цикле, или реализуйте прерывание.